# How to make "sticky" pages (and query by them)

Tags: query-posts, sticky-post

I have query_posts() with page_type set as 'page'. Is there any way I can make certain pages appear higher and thus, make them sticky?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear that there is any *obvious* way to enable "sticky post" support for Pages, e.g. via [`add_post_type_support()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support).

However, Pages support both hierarchy and menu order. I would recommend using menu order to output Pages in your preferred order.

Comment: Unfortunately, until these days (4 yrs after this question) sticky post option is still not available for other post type than `post`. The option is hard coded in the admin.

Answer (score -1):

Convert `Page` to `Post` type.

*Warning: May not preserve Custom Fields and Revision History, depending on which WP Converter plugin you use. To be careful, copy manually or with a WP Clone plugin the page before conversion, and Export your database for if you need to go back.*